# LLC converter design step

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, llc-converter

I read the [Infineon document](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Application_Note_Resonant+LLC+Converter+Operation+and+Design_Infineon.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a047ba0013a4a60e3be64a1) about LLC converter design.  On page 13, can anyone help to explain why this document uses this method to determine the maximum and minimum voltage gain?

Except for this one, do we have other methods that could determine the voltage gain?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

“Converter gain= switching bridge gain * resonant tank gain * transformer turn ratio (Ns/Np)” (Refer page no 4 same document).
The equations for Max.gain and Min.gain can be derived from this. The gain can be calculated using turn ratio as below. However, both concepts will match their final results.

[image]

We invite you to post your queries in [Infineon technical support centre](https://community.infineon.com/t5/Power/ct-p/Power).

Regards,
Guru

Comment: Guruprasad - Hi, From the wording in your answer "We invite you to post..." it seems you might be representing Infineon. If so, please note the rule about [promotion](/help/promotion) here. You must fully disclose any affiliation with anything you mention or link (i.e. anything you promote) in a post here. If this applies to you, please [edit] your post and add: "Disclosure: I work for Infineon" (or whatever explains your apparent promotion here). Please also read the [tour] and [help] to see the main site rules. Thanks. (Also, please [remove your "signature"](/help/behavior).)